# FusionCharts HeatMap: Display zeroes instead of blanks/missing values

Tags: charts, default, visualization, heatmap, fusioncharts

Is it possible to display "0" in FusionCharts Heatmap instead of blanks (missing values)? For example now it looks like this:

[image: FusionCharts Heatmap]

I'd like to display 0 instead of missing/blank values.

Comment: I don't really see a big problem with this question, and the ignorant comments make me sad. 13 comments deleted.

Comment: @Shog9 - what kind of comments were ignorant?

Comment: @Shog9 - its not a **big** problem, but if such a question would be asked without bounty - it will be downvoted with questions "what have you done?" or "show your research" or "what have you tried" etc.

Comment: Except, it *wasn't*, @MikroDel. Until you called it out on MSO a few hours ago, this question had *no* attention given to it - no votes, no flags, no comments. That's *probably* why it had a bounty offered on it. Please [see my updated answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199190/why-question-with-open-bounty-cannot-be-closed/199212#199212) for details on why I feel this discussion was unproductive.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for understanding. This is *exactly* why I added the bounty - to attract some attention after the question received none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to overwhelming support by SO community, I went back to my original research of this question.

Turned out the solution was obvious and right under my own nose. Originally the individual chart elements were collected in a StringBuilder like this (VB.NET/ASP.NET code)

```
chartSB.AppendFormat("<set rowId='{0}' columnId='{1}' value='{2}'  ", rowID, colName, value)
```

if the "value" has actual value - it's displayed, but if it contains `DbNull` - it is displayed as blank. I didn't want to modify original dataset that feeds the chart, but I don't have to. If I replace `DbNull` with "0" just for the rendering - this does the trick:

```
chartSB.AppendFormat("<set rowId='{0}' columnId='{1}' value='{2}'  ", rowID, colName,  If(IsDBNull(value), "0", value))
```

Comment: Yes downvotes is a really forceful encouragement ain't it? It's also fascinating to observe how they snowballing. I wonder if I just should delete entire thing and be over with.

Comment: Downvoted without any comment - its a problem, but with an explanation - its a way to comminicate what should you do to avoid downvoting